# Windows Update Error 0x80070422

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

So whenever I try to update my windows 10, I get an error saying there were some problems trying to install updates.

I tried to fix it by follow this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lnl80K9HGA but on the last step I get 'Access is dienied' error.

Does anyone know how to fix any of this?

[Windows update error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy37I.png)

[Access is dienied error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96gSZ.png)

Added more info:

[Windows Update service configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaTCm.png)

[Information from winver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqV6e.png)

Comment: Please edit your question to include what version of Windows 10 you are running.  You should indicate what the last cumulative update that was installed is exactly.  You should also provide the relevant information from **winver**.  Your question cannot be answered without this information.

Comment: @SimonG: Check the Windows Update service configuration. To do so, right-click Start, click Run. Type `cmd /k sc qc wuauserv`. Copy the output and post it here.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information, just added it the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I've been posting this everywhere....try this:
Open this link to Download the latest Windows 10 ISO : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
You have two options: Download the full ISO using the media creation tool or 
Click update now ...and let us know what happens !!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/890318)

Comment: @RajeshS did u get my answer deleted or something ?? I already edited it..so what is this FormReview ..How do i remove it from that form review page

Comment: ,, While review the whole text appears ,,, and during `Review for Editing`, the Reviewer can decide to approve or not !

Comment: That worked! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

*(From: [Fix: Windows Update Error 0x80070422 in Windows 10](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/fix-windows-update-error-0x80070422-in-windows-10/))*

Open admin Command Prompt and execute the following command:

```
sc config wuauserv start= demand
```

Restart Windows and see if the Windows Update service starts correctly.

If you receive **Access Denied** error when running the above command, try resetting the Windows Update service registry key permissions to default.

Download RegASSASSIN from Malwarebytes and run it.
Input the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv
```

In RegASSASSIN, don't forget to **UNCHECK** the `Delete registry key and all subkeys` checkbox before clicking on the `Delete` button.

You can use `RegASSASSIN` utility from Malwarebytes to reset the registry permissions for this key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv`

[image]

Now, see if you can change the Windows Update service Startup type using the Services MMC or Command Prompt.

Comment: Doesn't work, I still get an access is denied error in the cmd

Comment: Are you sure you're running that command from an Administrator Command Prompt window? To open one, type cmd.exe start, right-click Command Prompt (from Start search results) and click Run as Administrator.

Comment: Yea I do just that and still get the error

Comment: Pls check my updated answer.

Comment: I did that with RegASSASSIN and still the access is being denied

Comment: Can you go into this registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\wuauserv` using Regedit.exe and set the Start DWORD value to `3` ?

This may work because registry permissions are different from service control permissions.

After editing the registry, restart Windows.

Comment: When I try doing that, I get an error saying: "Cannot edit Start: Error writing the value's new contents."

Comment: Another option would be to use [AdvancedRun](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/advanced_run.html) to start `Regedit.exe` under the **SYSTEM** account, and update the registry value.

Answer (score 0):

> If you get access is denied error, use the default admin account and update from there. You can also fix your user's permissions or make a backup and start over.

**From elevated command prompt, type**
`net user administrator /active:yes`

You still need to restart the Windows Update service.

Log in as Administrator.
Open **Administrative Tools** from Control Panel.
Double-click **Services**.
Authenticate.

Find the Windows Update service, right-click **Properties**.

On the General tab, next to Startup type, make sure that **Automatic is selected**. Next to Service status, check to see if the service is started. If it is not, **click Start**.
Authenticate.

Now check for updates as usual.

[Microsoft Support Thread](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors)

Comment: The thing is that I am using the default admin account and yet still get the access is denied message

Comment: @SimonG - You made no mention of the fact you were using the built-in Administrator account.  You should edit your question, to reflect that fact, that is vital information necessary to answer your question.